# Quartz API: Job gets called immediately even though scheduled for later

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am creating a JobDetail as below,

```
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).withIdentity(queryId).usingJobData("ExecutionDelay",1).build();
```

I want it to first run after 1 hour.

The Trigger for the same is as below,

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInHours(1)).build();
```

But, when I am creating more than 1 Thread of the above code in a class, the Job gets triggered immediately for some of the Jobs.

Not sure what is wrong. Can some one help.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because you do not set the [start time](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/impl/triggers/SimpleTriggerImpl.html#setStartTime%28java.util.Date%29) when you create your trigger. If you do not set the start time explicitely, then the current time (new Date()) is assumed and then depending on the your trigger's misfire instruction (default is [SMART_POLICY](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/Trigger.html#MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_SMART_POLICY)) and timing, the job may be fired immediately.

To solve the problem, you will need to set the trigger's start time to "new Date() + 1 hour".